# Does Rei's favourite drink exist in real life?

Tags: merchandise, digimon

In **Digimon Universe: Appli Monsters**, Gatchmon in the fourth episode, falls in love with (and totally an intentional product placement) what's dubbed as "Gatchi Sweets" or "GatchiMonaka", which is wafer biscuit with bean fillings.

[image: Gatchi Sweets/Gatchimonaka in the anime (left) and real-life (right)]

---

Frequently across episodes, we also see Rei, one of the protagonist characters frequently drinking small packets of a "Choo Choo Energy" drink of some sort.

[image: Rei gifting a large pack of his favourite energy drink to Dantemon in Episode 33]

## What exact is that, and does it have a real-world equivalent; physical thing?

*... or is that drink totally and utterly fictional?*

Comment: Regarding the GatchiSweets (or *GachiMonaka*), I don't think it's an intentional product placement. Rather, [it's a fictional product being made into real-life](https://wikimon.net/Gatch_Monaka).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the in-work name is fictional, it is based off of real products: jelly drinks. More or less, all jelly-type drinks are in a semi-hard bag with a mouth to drink from on the top. And most of these drinks usually serve some health-oriented purpose, quick energy boost, daily vitamin intake, etc. There are many jelly drinks, and one that is very popular (and most likely the model) is the Weider drinks.

[Here's the website for Weider's jelly products.](http://www.weider-jp.com/jelly/)